# Two disjoint closed sets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that there does not exist $ϵ$ with $d(A, B)> ϵ$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that there exist two disjoint closed sets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that there does not exist a positive $ϵ$ with $d(x, y)\ge ϵ$ where $x∈A$ and $y∈B$.

I have already proved that if $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed, then there exist a positive $ϵ$ such that $d(x, y)\geϵ$. So for the question that we need to prove, we need to assume that none of $A$ and $B$ are bounded. But how does the unbounded property help to prove this one?

Answer (score 4):

Let
$$A=\{2,3,4\ldots\}\ ,\quad B=\{2\tfrac12,3\tfrac13,4\tfrac14,\ldots\}\ .$$

Comment: Nice example +1!

Answer (score 1):

$A=\bigcup_{i=2}^\infty \{i\}$, $B=\bigcup_{i=2}^\infty [i+1/i,i+2/3]$, since $i+1/i$ approaches $i$ as closely as we wish for large $i$.